# How to Replicate Survival Analysis Conducted in Stata to R

Tags: r, survival, stata, cox-model

I am curious on how to replicate the results of a Cox model estimated in Stata in R. I get completely different results, and I think I understand why (but I am unsure of how to fix it), but before I discuss that, I will present a glimpse of the data I am working with along with the simplified syntax to illustrate my problem.

An idea of the data:
[image]

"Failure" denotes an instance of a country experiencing conflict recurrence (this is just dummy data here so its not accurate) and "peace_sp_id" is a unique numeric ID value for a spell of peace. So now, I will run a model in both Stata and R (with the real data), provide the syntax and model outputs:

Stata:
`stset year, id(peace_sp_id) failure(failure)`
`stcox GDP`

R:
`coxm1 <- coxph(Surv(year, failure) ~ GDP, data = chapter1data)`
`coxm1`

A big difference that I notice is that I'm not sure how to recreate the `id(peace_sp_id)` aspect in R. This is important since each row in this data set is *not* an independent observation from the other. Is there a way to re-create the "multiple-record ID variable" option in R that Stata provides?

Comment: You might look at the `cluster` function in the coxph formula.

Answer (score 0):

(`year` might not be the correct time variable to `stset` on, but can't say for sure because your posted data snippet's dummy data.  Let's bracket that issue, for now.)

The `id()` option for `stset` doesn't adjust the standard errors or coefficients in the way you're potentially thinking.  `id()` only impacts how `_t0` and `_t` are defined:

```stata
webuse diet2, clear

stset dox, id(id) failure(fail)
list id _st-_t0 in 1/5

stset dox, failure(fail)
list id _st-_t0 in 1/5
```

`_t0` and `_t` are often referred to as "start" and "stop" variables, from counting-process notation.

In R, you need to generate the start and stop variables yourself.  When you specify your Cox model, you'll then pass three arguments to `Surv()` instead of two:

```r
coxm1 <- coxph(Surv(YOUR_NEW_START_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE, year, failure) ~ GDP, 
               data = chapter1data, ties="breslow")
```

Note, too, the addition of `ties="breslow"` to `coxph()`, to match `stcox`'s default tie correction.

With your dataset snippet (and continuing with the initial `stset` syntax you provided), I suspect `chapter1data$year0 <- year - 1` will get you what you need.  Verify that by checking `_t0`'s values in Stata after running your current `stset` statement, though.

(Or, alternatively: save your dataset in Stata after you `stset`, import that dataset into R, then:

```r
coxph(Surv(`_t0`, `_t`, `_d`) ~ GDP, data = chapter1data_stset, ties="breslow")
```

)